# How to merge a branch in Git to another branch with different remote repoisitry

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, pull-request

I have the below structure in Git:

```
-master
--dev   (check out form master)
---feature1   (check out form dev)
---feature2   (check out form dev)
```

When we need to make a hot release we do a check out from the master branch as follows:

```
-master
--hotrelease.v7.9 (check out from master)
```

I merge a pull request from hotrelease.v7.9 to master and release it. Nut my concern is to merge a pull request to dev branch to push my code to development branch.

But the issue that the dev branch is not up to date with the hot releases that checked out from the master.

Comment: If you've merged the hot release into master, then you should only need to merge master into dev. That sounds pretty straightforward to me. (You might also need to merge dev into feature1, etc., to catch them up.)

Comment: I tried this solution but the master branch and dev branch are different source repositories. Where at the end of the release we merge dev to master but in case of hot release I don't need to make double developement to dev and hot branch. My concern is to commit to hot release branch and merge it with master then merge it with dev instead of rewrite the same code in the dev and push it.

Comment: Merging is supposed to save you from double development. Why are you opposed to merging the hot release into your dev branch? You might be able to just merge dev into master if there are no conflicts, but you'll need to merge master back into dev at some point otherwise your dev branch will drift too far from master.

Answer (score 1):

## Push to master after hotfix released

### To push hotfix to master

1. Change to master branch and get latest if someone's push happend

> git checkout master
>
> git pull

2. Chnage to hotfixbranch and merge master to hotfix if someone pushed their changes to master while you work on hotfix, so that you may get conflicts to solve

> git checkout hotfix
>
> git merge --no-ff origin master

3. Merge hotfix branch to master

> git checkout master
>
> git merge --no-ff origin hotfix-branch-name

### Merge master to develop to feature to getlatest into individual feature branches.

Step 1: Get Latest to develop

> git checkout master
>
> git pull
>
> git checkout develop
>
> git pull
>
> git merge --no-ff origin master # to get latest chnages from master to develop

Step 2 : Merge develop to feature1 to get latest from develop so that feature one will get hotfic changes.

> git checkout feature1
>
> git merge --no-ff origin develop
>
> git push -u origin feature1

Step 3: Repeat the same for the feature2 branch

Comment: Thank you Jinna for your comment. My concern is to merge the hotfix branch to dev branch after releasing it (meaning that I did the merge from hotfix to master) and I am not asking about the feature branch.

Comment: Your hotfix is merged to master, master will be merged to develop, from develop we merge develop to featurebranch

Comment: updated my answer now for hotfix. and even for feature branches. Accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I will test your suggestion and get back to you. Thank you @Jinna Balu.